# Eclipse - show only tabs from working set

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to show/filter the open tabs by the currently selected working set ?
I mean, when I select a working set the editor view only show the related files.

I've searched around in google, stackoverflow and eclipse market, but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.  I believe the reason is that if you try to open another file that is not in the working set (e.g. You want to open the declaration of a class in the source code), then you get into a contradiction.  You've said that you only want tabs from the working set, but you're also asking for a tab that's not in the working set.

I suppose it's possible to write a plugin that on request will close any editor that's open on a file not in the working set, but that's about the best you could do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Mylyn [task focused interface](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Task-Focused_Interface).

It does not exactly what you are looking for, but it is the closest tool that I can think of.

Comment: Yes, @zeropouet, its not exactly what I was lookin for, but its for sure a option to evaluate, thanks